# Skeptics.se podcast #3

Tags: discussion, podcast

[This episode](https://soundcloud.com/user9210836/skeptics-stack-exchange-podcast-s01-e03) focuses on Climate Change. We have a lot of questions on the site about it, but we are missing some canonical content. This is an opportunity for the community to look at some old one and make them better

### Questions

- [Do human activities contribute to climate change?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/41/do-human-activities-contribute-to-climate-change)
- [Did we have global cooling 40 years ago?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2667/did-we-have-a-global-cooling-40-years-ago)
- [Is CO<sub>2</sub> the cause of global warming?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3435/is-co%E2%82%82-the-cause-for-global-warming)
- [Did the arctic ice sheet grow by 60% from 2012 to 2013?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/17695/did-the-arctic-ice-sheet-grow-by-60-from-2012-to-2013)

### Hot Questions for the week

- [Does broccoli have a nervous system?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/32932/does-broccoli-have-a-nervous-system)
- [Lung cancer due to inhaling oily steam in the restaurant kitchen for a long period of time](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/32925/lung-cancer-due-to-inhaling-oily-steam-in-the-restaurant-kitchen-for-a-long-peri)
- [Are people more likely on average to die in an extinction event than in a car crash?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/32866/are-people-on-average-more-likely-to-die-in-an-extinction-event-than-in-a-car-cr)

### User Shout Outs

Top Users:  [Gareth Rees](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/14749/gareth-rees), [DavePhD](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/25579/davephd), [vartec](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/3790/vartec), [Yasashii Eirian](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/28984/%E5%84%AA%E3%81%97%E3%81%84%E3%82%A8%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AA%E3%82%A2%E3%83%B3)

Welcome New user: [Sour Lolita](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/32891/sour-lolita)

#### Credits

Questions and Answer courtesy of [Skeptics Stack Exchange](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com)

Music courtesy of [Symphony of Science by MelodySheep](http://www.symphonyofscience.com/) used under CC license

You can download from or listen at [SoundCloud](https://soundcloud.com/user9210836/skeptics-stack-exchange-podcast-s01-e03), or follow on [TuneIn](http://tunein.com/radio/Skeptics-Stack-Exchange-Podcast-p869154/). A podcast [RSS feed](http://feeds.soundcloud.com/users/soundcloud:users:2636145/sounds.rss) is also available.

Comment: Note to self: Add podcast link to Welcome to Skeptics page.